# Analytic function that maps upper half plane to upper half plane given two distinct values

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Let $f$ be an analytic function that maps upper half plane to itself. Also, let $f(i)=i, \ f(2i)=\frac{i}{2}$. Then, what can be said about $|f(1+i)|$?

Now, by using the Schwarz-pick lemma and its corollary ineqaulity, we may observe that $f$ is a Mobius transformation with positive determinant. But then, the problem arises as to whether the value of $|f(1+i)|$ can be determined precisely. This is because, three points are at the least required to completely determine the Mobius transformations. So how do we determine $|f(1+i)|$? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The question is not to determine $f(1+i)$ but what can be said about its absolute value.

Comment: @AnneBauval ok, so do you mean we have to use somehow the property that upper half plane is conformal to unit disk and then use it to get something?

Comment: Sorry, no idea.

Comment: $-1/z$ is one such function. Perhaps identity theorem is your friend.

Comment: @NinadMunshi but for identity theorem, the region of equality should have limit points right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $g=\phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ where $\phi(z)= \frac{z-i}{z+i}$ is an isomorphism $\Bbb{H\to D}$ sending $i$ to $0$.

So $g$ maps $\Bbb{D\to D}$ to itself and $g(0)=0, g(1/3)=g(\phi(2i)=\phi(f(2i))=\phi(i/2)=-1/3$.

Schwarz lemma gives that  $g(z)=-z$.

Therefore $f(z) = -1/z$.

Comment: Thanks, but how can we say that $f$ is an automotphism of the upper half plane? It is not given as a bijection right?

Comment: Also, could you please elaborate how $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})=Aut(\mathbb{H})$ implies that $f(i)=i\implies f(z)=\frac{az+b}{-bz+a}$?

Comment: @vidyarthi Sorry I misinterpreted your question. I edited

Comment: Thanks! this method would then mean that we could then convert any analytic function as a part of bijection over its domain. So, does this in any way similarly help in analytic continuation?